# How to pass a function to the scope with pymongo.map_reduce

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Can someone provide an example with the the correct syntax to pass a function to the scope parameter when using pymongo's [*map_reduce*](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=map_reduce#pymongo.collection.Collection.map_reduce).

So far I have only found examples of passing a function in javascript ([How to use variables in MongoDB Map-reduce map function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273379/how-to-use-variables-in-mongodb-map-reduce-map-function)), and passing variables with pymongo ([Map reduce execute failed with pymongo but success in mongo shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012236/map-reduce-execute-failed-with-pymongo-but-success-in-mongo-shell)).

Upon trying I am always getting "TypeError: foo is not a function", and from the server logs it looks like it has taken the function I passed to the scope as a string.

Answer (score 1):

I fiddled with this quite a bit today.  The `scope` keyword argument needs to be a dictionary. If you want to define a variable that will be a function in the scope of the mapper, put its name as the key, and provide the function declaration wrapped in a `Code()` constructor.  Here's what should be a working example with MongoDB v3.2.8 and pymongo v3.3.1:

```
import pymongo
import bson

db = pymongo.MongoClient().test

db['test-input'].insert_many([
    {'foo': 'bar', 'angle': 0},
    {'foo': 'bar', 'angle': 90},
    {'foo': 'baz', 'angle': -90}
])

mapper = bson.Code(
    """
        function map() {
            emit(this.foo, radians(this.angle))
        }
    """
)

reducer = bson.Code(
    """
        function reduce(key, values) {
            var avg = 0;
            for (i in values) {
                avg += values[i];
            }
            return avg / values.length;
        }
    """
)

output_collection = db['test-input'].map_reduce(
    mapper, reducer, 'test-output',
    scope={
        'radians': bson.Code("function(x) {return x * Math.PI / 180}")
    }
)

print [x for x in output_collection.find()]
```